# Not able to read ConfigurationManager.AppSettings on HostType("Moles")

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, moles, pex-and-moles

If  HostType as Moles, then i can't get data via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Its work fine for me 2-3 months before. But it is not worked and all my test cases are failed (raised the null reference exception).

Please help me to fix. thanks.

[Related thread raised in MSDN also](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsunittest/thread/72425107-2e7a-4815-8953-cd5b98a0ae02)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in current versions of Moles in .Net 4.0 - You can Mole the configuration manager and have it return the values that you want as a workaround.

As an example, This is how I setup a test for a Linq To SQL DataContext to get code coverage for a default constructor without connecting to SQL.

```
[TestInitialize]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void Setup()
{
    MCodesConfigurationHelper.DataAccessSettingsGet = () =>
    {
        MCodesDataAccessSettings setting = new MCodesDataAccessSettings();
        setting.DatabaseConnectionStringGet = () => { return "this is a connection string."; };
        return setting;
    };

    MConfigurationManager.ConnectionStringsGet = () =>
    {
        MConnectionStringSettingsCollection strings = new MConnectionStringSettingsCollection();
        strings.ItemGetString = (string connectionString) =>
        {
            var cstring = new MConnectionStringSettings();
            cstring.ToString = () => { return connectionString; };
            cstring.ConnectionStringGet = () => { return connectionString; };
            return cstring;
        };
        return strings;
    };
    MDataContext.ConstructorString = (DataContext dataContext, string connection) => { };
}


[TestMethod]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void DefaultConstructorTest()
{
    using (MyDataContext target = new MyDataContext())
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree your point that after update the Moles from academic to latest 4.0 version only i got the configuration issue. But my need is to access the app.config for the database and app-setting key to access for many methods. So please update if any solution or fix for this.